# jQuery scroll div animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that this animate is only possible when i scroll in the 0 - 200 area. When I'm in the 201 - area this animation do nothing. When you  click on the yellow div the navigation moves up but i want that the navigation stands still when i click on it above 200 scroll pixels. How is that possible? I'm trying to solve that for hours but i find no solution.

[Updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/38/)

```
/* MAIN FUNCTION */

var $a = $(".a"),
$b = $(".b"),
$c = $(".c");

function anim1() {
    $b.animate({width: 395}, {duration: 300, complete: anim2});
}

function anim2() {
    $a.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 400});
    $c.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 400});
}

$(".b").click(function() {
    anim1();
});

function anim10() {
    $c.animate({top:"-50px"}, {duration: 200});
    $a.animate({top:"-50px"}, {duration: 200 , complete: anim20});
}

function anim20() {
    $b.animate({width: 137}, {duration: 200});
}

$(".ab").click(function() {
    anim10();
});

/* MY SOLUTION?! */


$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
         $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {anim10();});
    } 
    else
    {     
         /*  DO NOTHING ! How is that possible */
    }
});

/* SLIDE UP ONLY MAIN NAVIGATION */

$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
        $(".example").animate({top:"0px"},{duration: 50,easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});
    } 
    else
    {     
        $(".example").animate({top:"-50px"},{duration: 50,easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough breaks in your html

Comment: hihi Isn't it easier to set `body{height: goCrazy ;}` instead of all those `<br>` :)

Comment: :D its only that i can scroll :D